# C# - ASP.NET MVC - Url.Action got HTTP 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Having an error of

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404.

I'm trying to do a POST method in my MVC using razor. In my controller:

**ServiceListController**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
private ActionResult GetData(string txtTech, string txtSerial, string txtJobNo)
{ 
    return View();
}
```

In my I've used the Url.Action. But when pressing the button filter, the **Requested URL: /ServiceList/GetData** The resource cannot be found. Do I need to add to routes or something?

```
<form action="@Url.Action("GetData", "ServiceList")" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table style="width: 400px">
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Technician", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
                <input type="text" id="txtTech" name="txtTech" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Serial", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
                <input type="text" id="txtSerial" name="txtSerial" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Job No", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
                <input type="text" id="txtJobNo" name="txtJobNo" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })
                @Html.DropDownList("txtStatus", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(wmssoft_srm.Models.Status))), "Status", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 200px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        ....
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btFilter">Clear Filter</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Because you `[HttpPost]` method is `private` - make it `public`

Comment: Change GetData method private sccess specifier to public.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much! Didn't notice it.

Comment: @AjasAju are you sure?

Comment: @SeM.Nop.i edited my answer.that was a wrong thought.

Comment: @StephenMuecke But after changing it to **public** The view 'GetData' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.

Comment: Well clearly you do not have a view named `GetData.cshtml` in that folder. But if you want to return `Index.cshtml` view then its `returnView("Index");` (but if that the case, your `[HttpPost]` method should also be named `Index` and its just `@using (Html.BeginForm()) { ...`

Comment: And FGS - use a view model and strongly bind to it using the `@HtmlHelper` methods and make the parameter of your POST method the model)

Answer (score 0):

try using this html.beginform like this and make post method public

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("GetData", "ServiceList", FormMethod.Post))
{ @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table style="width: 400px">
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Technician", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
            <input type="text" id="txtTech" name="txtTech" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Serial", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
            <input type="text" id="txtSerial" name="txtSerial" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Job No", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
            <input type="text" id="txtJobNo" name="txtJobNo" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })
            @Html.DropDownList("txtStatus", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(wmssoft_srm.Models.Status))), "Status", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 200px;" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    ....
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btFilter">Clear Filter</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This
>
> ServiceListController

Your Method is update for

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
Public ActionResult GetData(string txtTech, string txtSerial, string txtJobNo)
{ 
    return View();
}
```

Update View Action
You Can Try Two Way

> 1)

```
<form action="@Url.Action("GetData", "ServiceList")" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table style="width: 400px">
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Technician", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
                <input type="text" id="txtTech" name="txtTech" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Serial", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
                <input type="text" id="txtSerial" name="txtSerial" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("Job No", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
                <input type="text" id="txtJobNo" name="txtJobNo" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
            </td>
            <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
            <td>
                @Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })
                @Html.DropDownList("txtStatus", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(wmssoft_srm.Models.Status))), "Status", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 200px;" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        ....
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btFilter">Clear Filter</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

2)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetData", "ServiceList", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<table style="width: 400px">
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Technician", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
            <input type="text" id="txtTech" name="txtTech" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Serial", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
            <input type="text" id="txtSerial" name="txtSerial" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("Job No", new { style = "width: 50px;" })
            <input type="text" id="txtJobNo" name="txtJobNo" class="form-control" style="width: 200px" />
        </td>
        <td>@Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })</td>
        <td>
            @Html.Label("a", new { style = "visibility: hidden;" })
            @Html.DropDownList("txtStatus", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(wmssoft_srm.Models.Status))), "Status", new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 200px;" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    ....
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btFilter">Clear Filter</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>}
```